# What's the name of the function that applies each function in a list of functions to a value progressively, accumulating the results?

Tags: haskell

It's like the title says. I've implemented this, but maybe this function already has a common name and exists in a standard library.

Other suggestions about this function are welcome. Maybe there is a cleaner implementation.

```
let transform x funcList = transform' x [x] funcList
        where transform' startVal accum funcList 
                   | null funcList = reverse accum
                   | otherwise = let result = (head funcList) startVal
                                     in transform' result (result:accum) $ tail funcList
```

When executed, it does this:

```
> transform 2 [(2 + ),((-1) +),(3 *)]
[2,4,3,9]
```

Comment: Since you asked about other suggestions: it's better to use pattern matching in your definition, and avoid partial list functions such as `head` or `tail`. Also, there's no need to use an accumulator here (and hence there's no need for using `reverse` either). Note that the proposed `scanl` solution would work on an infinite list of functions, whereas your solution doesn't.

Comment: You can write `((-1) +))` as `subtract 1`, by the way. Slightly more verbose, but clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define it with `scanl`:

```
let transform = scanl (\v f -> f v)
```

or

```
let transform = scanl (flip ($))
```

Comment: thanks! that's just what i was looking for. i suppose that might be too simple for "transform" to warrant its own name...

Comment: `flip ($)` could be written as `flip id`. If you squint at its type, you can see that `($)` is just a slightly type-restricted version of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion isn't far as nice as the `scanl` one, but perhaps it can offer a different view on the problem. We're doing a state-ful traversal. We convert each function to a `State` value that takes an input, applies the function to it and returns the value as well as puts it as the next state. Then all we need to do is to `mapM` over the whole list.

```
import Control.Monad.State

trans :: a -> [a -> a] -> [a]
trans s fs = s : evalState (mapM toState fs) s
  where
    -- join (,) just makes a tuple out of a value
    -- using the reader monad
    toState = state . (join (,) .)
```